# dismiss ModalViewController from another viewcontroller in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

The new 3.1 sdk allows for the UIImagepickerController to hide the camera controls and use your own controls via cameraOverlay view. So, I implemented the overlay view through another Viewcontroller:

```
CameraViewController *cameraController = [[CameraViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraViewController" bundle:nil];
self.cameraviewController = cameraController;

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.cameraOverlayView = cameraviewController.view;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[cameraController release];
[picker release];
```

The cameraviewController.view has the Cancel button. The problem I'm facing is how to dismiss the Modal view with that cancel button. I haven't found a way of referencing the controller which called the Modalview.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

need to add cameraController.delegate = self; and setup the delegate protocol in CameraViewController.